# How is webpack-serve different from webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-serve

`webpack-serve`: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-serve

`webpack-dev-server`: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server

They both state they're a dev server for webpack. How are they different?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
+-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
|                 |    webpack-dev-server    |    webpack-serve     |
+-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| Initial release | 23 Dec 2014              | 12 feb 2018          |
| Total releases  | 74                       | 7                    |
| Github stars    | 3449                     | 231                  |
| Lines of code   | 28301                    | 16075                |
| under the hood  | Express.js (22047 lines) | Koa.js (8913 lines)| |
| API             | not aligned              | API first            |
| Mode            | active (support, update) | deprecated (mar 2018)|
| Total           | work slower but supports | fast alternative     |
|                 |   old browsers           |                      |
+-----------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

**Sources**

- Official repos
- [Webpack-serve Up a Side of Whoop-Ass](http://shellscape.org/2018/02/12/webpack-serve-up-whoopass)
- [I investigated webpack-serve which seems to be the successor of webpack-dev-server](http://yami-beta.hateblo.jp/entry/2018/03/07/191730)
- [Gloc](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/github-gloc/kaodcnpebhdbpaeeemkiobcokcnegdki) (Chrome extension for line counting. All strings are considered)
- [Total section](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server#project-in-maintenance)

https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/7pg2rq/webpackdevserver_is_now_in_maintenance_mode/dsgwxjd/?st=jf286v37&sh=0336089c

Comment: Webpack-serve is now deprecated [sept 18, 2018](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-serve/commit/edaf28c6c935c3e29d26dbb02a9d6b672cc5148a).
Webpack-dev-server is in support and update mode again.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used webpack-serve but by looking at documents initial take is that it is relatively new repo (7 releases againest webpack-dev-server 70+) and focus is to use a browsers native WebSocket to fetch assets instead of polling mechanism. My guess is that would obviously make webpack-serve work better and faster while working in dev mode than webpack-dev-server.

This made curious about it. I would give it a try on my current setup and will try to get back with findings.

Comment: Did you try it? What's your experiences? It seems it can do much more than webpack-dev-server...